# Google form border…Is there a way to remove it or not? or even blend it with the background color pink

Tags: css, forms, wix

How do I remove the ash and white stripes border around the "Login-USE your Zip code Google form" or make it look negligible?

It is a form made using the Google forms

Is there a way to remove it or not? or even blend it with the background color pink in below image?

[image]

http://jrankins6.wix.com/team-iwate-2014

Comment: Haven't used Google Forms or Wix but here is a hint...http://i.stack.imgur.com/MAm7x.jpg

Answer (score 1):

From your editor on the right side where you have the option to change theme.

Notice the small icon in red for "Customize theme" click it to bring up the option listed in the second image, here you want to play with your Form Background and Page Background, from Page Background you can remove or change the image (the stripe you refer to) and adjust your color.